# Cantor set has no isolated point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

If someone could check my proof, I would really appreciate it. I am trying to prove some properties of the Cantor set. I have already proved that Cantor set $C$ is nonempty and has empty interior. I am trying to show that is has no isolated point.

> My Proof: Suppose there is an isolated point $x\in C$. Then $x \in \cap_{k\ge0} C_k$. Since $x$ is an isolated point, then there exists some $\alpha$ such that $(x-\alpha,x+\alpha) \cap C =\{x\}$. This implies that for any $k\ge 0$, we have $(x-\alpha,x+\alpha)\cap C_k = \{x\}$.
>
> However, this is impossible. No matter how small $\alpha$ is, there always exists $m$ such that $\frac{1}{3^m} < \alpha$. So $x+\frac{1}{3^m}\in (x-\alpha,x+\alpha).$ Thus $(x-\alpha,x+\alpha)\cap C_k = \{x\}$ cannot only have $x$.

I am having trouble of making myself more clear. I suppose I get the idea right though...

Comment: What are the $C_k$'s in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $C_k$ is the union of closed intervals that constitute the $k$th stage in constructing the Cantor set.

> This implies that for any $k\geq 0$, we have $(x-\alpha,a+\alpha)\cap C_k=\{x\}.$

This is not true. We do know that for every $y\in (x-\alpha,x+\alpha)$ with $y\neq x$ that there exists a particular $k$ such that $y\not\in C_k$. But we so not know that every $C_k$ contains none of the points of $(x-\alpha,x+\alpha)$ except $x$.

Another way to prove the desired result is to use the idea you mention in the next paragraph. For each $k$, $x$ is in a subinterval of $C_k$ which has an endpoint $a_k$ which is a distance less than $1/3^k$ from $x$. Show that the sequence $a_k$ converges to $x$.

Also note that just because $x\in C$ does not mean that $x+1/3^k\in C$.